# PHP - Generate 4 digit alpha numeric code based on another number

Tags: php

Would like to generate a 4 (or more) digit alphanumeric code based on another number. Have tried using the base_convert method but I do not want the number to be guessable from the code.

Have managed to generate a random 4 digit alphanumeric code.

```
    $numOfAlphabets = rand(0,4);
    $numOfNumbers = 4 - $numOfAlphabets;

    $character_set_array = array();
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => $numOfAlphabets, 'characters' => 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => $numOfNumbers, 'characters' => '0123456789');
    $temp_array = array();

    foreach ($character_set_array as $character_set) 
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $character_set['count']; $i++) 
        {
            $temp_array[] = $character_set['characters'][rand(0, strlen($character_set['characters']) - 1)];
        }
    }

    shuffle($temp_array);
    return implode('', $temp_array);
```

A thought is to convert the number into binary and then XOR it with a fixed number so that I can retrieve the number from the code.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: You could use `range()` function of PHP, instead of those 2 arrays: `$array = range('a', 'z');` or `$array = range('0', '9');`   http://php.net/range

Comment: @artur99 Right agreed. Just temp code. Need to work on it further once I have solution to my problem.